# How to wrap the list for bootstrap-multiselect (Davidstutz)

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-multiselect

My list items are too long. Can I make them wrap?

This is how I declare my multi-select.

```
        $('#ExpensesClaimList').multiselect({
            numberDisplayed: 1,
            dropRight: true,
            buttonTextAlignment: 'left',
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            nonSelectedText: 'Select ' + '@DocTypes.GetModuleName(DocTypes.ExpensesClaim)'
        });
```

This is my CSS

```
.multiselect {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 280px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

[Currently it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzDLW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try `word-wrap: break-word;`

```css
.con {
  max-width: 280px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">asddasddasdasdsasddasdasdasdsdsdsdsdaasdsdddasdkasdkkdskdskasdkksdkdkdksdskskskskskskskskskksasddasddasdasdsasddasdasdasdsdsdsdsdaasdsdddasdkasdkkdskdskasdkksdkdkdksdskskskskskskskskskks</div>
```